# WIQL - Querying description for exact phrase

Tags: tfs, wiql

in TFS I am struggling to produce a query that searches the description field for an exact phrase e.g. "DO 1.2".

The query matches both DO and 1.2 and DO1.2 when I really want to just match the exact string.

**Sample of the clause in the query**

```
[System.Description] CONTAINS 'DO 1.2'
```

Is it possible to exactly match what I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't, this because the description field is long-text field and the full text search will be applied on it and you can't use = with long-text field

Comment: That is absolutely true. The only way of querying this is turning off full text search and recycle the AT